# При удерживании кнопку нажатой изменить фон

Tags: android

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы когда кнопку удерживаешь нажатой, менялся ее фон плавно или хотя бы не плавно?

Comment: Для второго вопроса задайте отдельный вопрос. Правило - один вопрос-один вопрос. По первому вопросу - вам нужен селектор

Comment: А можно код привести по первому вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте в папке `res/drawable` `xml` файл с именем `selector.xml` и вот таким содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/red" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/green" />
</selector>
```

2. Задайте его в качестве фона для любой вьюхи через атрибут `android:backround` так:

```
<View
    ...
    android:backround="@drawable/selector"/>
```

Таким образом при нажатии вьюха будет окрашиваться в красный, а во всех остальных случаях - в зелёный

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо.

Comment: @kolhoz, если один из ответов решает вашу задачу вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав галочку слева от тела ответа

Answer (score 1):

Используйте фреймворк [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

```
int colorFrom = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
int colorTo = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // миллисекунд
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        mLayout.setBackgroundColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue()); mLayout - ваш фоновый Layout
    }

});
```

И удерживание по кнопке

```
 mButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    colorAnimation.start();
                    return false;
                }
 });
```